# Python - urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request (Youtube API).

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, urllib2

I'm using Youtube API to open a search result. My hope is to open the search result, append the results into JSON and create a list from these results. I tested the url and it works with my API key. But I'm getting:

```
> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request error.
```

. Would anybody know how I can successfully open this URL? I'm using Python 3.5, but I will take suggestions in 2.7 as well. 
In python2.7 I tried using `urllib2.quote(url)` but it didn't work. I got the same error.

```
search = input('Search for a Video:')
```

Input: Cat Videos

```
urllib.parse.parse_qsl(search)
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet+&maxResults=5&order=rating&q='+search+'&key='+API_KEY
 with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response: 
    html = response.read()
```

. Exception Error:

```
 Search for a Video:cat videos
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Project.py", line 15, in <module>
        with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response: 
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 162, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 471, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 581, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 509, in error
        return self._call_chain(*args)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 589, in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Answer (score 0):

This shit is not letting me comment yet so...
Have you tried using the examples in [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python?hl=es#search_by_keyword)?

You need an auth_token for your application before you can move on with your request, there is not enough context in what you show for telling you're actually implementing OAuth but I'd start from there, is not likely that this thing is going to work in a Curl like way just like that.

However, for your example you could just pull the results from a GET unfancy call not to the API but the frontend, e.g.:

`https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=cute+cats`

**Edit:**
The reason for the bad request (400) is due to the lack or url encoding in the search arguments.
A wrong configuration on the API may cause (403) errors

Comment: So for your code to work you'd need to add something like this to URL: `url = 'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=' + search.replace(' ','+')`
Also, there is no real need to use the API if you're not implementing OAuth (just won't work), think about **beautifulsoup** or **lxml** instead (I'd totally go for OAuth as my first choice)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm building a simple search app and I believe I read in one of Google Dev page that a basic API Key will work. I'm using the API key because I need to open the results in a JSON page. I'm later going to use that JSON page to parse data and create a list with my search results. I tested opening the url by using `webbrowser.open(url)` and it worked. Just urllib that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: I see what you mean. This is not a urllib error but from the API settings at your google console, you have a domain or source restriction defined. Tried your code and it works, when the configuration on the API end is correct.
Almost forget, you **must** URL encode your search values: `"Cat Videos" != "Cat%20Videos"`